# One dimensional invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

So , I know that all eigenspaces of the linear operator are invariant subspaces for that operator. My question is :
If we have ONE  dimensional invariant subspace $L$ for linear operator $A$, is that 
$L$ subspace of eigenspace for $A$ or is that $L$ the whole eigenspace ?
I know how to prove that $L$ is the subspace of eigenspace for $A$ , but is it the whole eigenspace ?

Comment: It an be either...

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking: "If I have a one dimensional invariant subspace $L,$ is $L$ an eigenspace? And if $L$ is invariant, then does that mean $L$ is the entire eigenspace?"

Comment: onedimensional L , yes .

Comment: Certainly not: For the identity operator, the eigenspace is the whole vector space and all invariant subspaces are invariant, so for vector spaces of dimension $> 1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example

$$A=I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;L=\text{Span}\,\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}(1,1,1)\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Thus $\;\dim L=1\;$ and it is $\;A\,-$ invariant, yet the whole eigenspace ( of the *unique* eigenvector $\;1\;$) is the whole $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ ...